# TEXTJOIN of INDEX MATCH matching table headers if values aren't blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching, textjoin, excel-tables

On cell E2 I'm trying to get a TEXTJOIN with delimiter ", " (comma and a space) of INDEX MATCH to the prices you see on the right.
For example the price of an apple is $$$ and also A2 is not blank so the formula will match the header of A2 (and not A2 itself) to column G.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(H2:H5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:C2<>"",A1:C1,"")),G2:G5))))
```

If you do not have `FILTER()` function then try below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(H2:H5,IFERROR(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:C2<>"",A1:C1,"")),G2:G5,0),"")),""))
```

You may need to array entry this formula for non-365 version of excel. Array entry means enter formula as `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: The second one did the trick, without having to use an array formula (it's weird I have 365 but the first one didn't work) Thank you very much!